# fgets in function gets segmentation fault with a variable, but not with hard coded string

Tags: c, string, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to loop through a `.desktop` file and get some values out of it, line-by-line, and storing it all inside of a structure. I want to do this with many files, so it's important to be able to store a file path as a variable and send that to the function.

Here is the function that is getting the error:

```
App * ParseApp (char * path) {
    printf("Path: %s\n", path);

    FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
    char line[256];

    App * app = malloc(sizeof(struct App));

    printf("Malloc worked. sizeof line: %li\n", sizeof(line));

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("about to parse line\n");
        ParseLine(app, line);
    }

    return app;
}
```

The following code *does* work, and outputs the value expected:

```
App * app = ParseApp("/usr/share/applications/Android Studio.desktop");
printf("Name: %s", app->name);
```

However, when using a variable to pass the filepath as an argument, I get a segfault:

```
char filepath[128];
strcpy(filepath, settings.folder);
strcat(filepath, "/");
strcat(filepath, filename);
App * app = ParseApp(filepath);
```

I am confident that fgets is where I am getting a segfault, because it properly outputs the file path at the start of the function, and it even gets past the malloc function:

```
Path: /usr/share/applications/Android Studio.desktop

Malloc worked. sizeof line: 256
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So it seems that only hard coded string values will work. I figured the issue might be a size issue with the string variable, but seeing as how it outputs the same way in either case, that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I added a check to see if the file is null:

```
App * ParseApp (char * path) {
    printf("Path: %s\n", path);

    FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
    char line[256];

    if (file == NULL)
        printf("file is null\n");

    App * app = malloc(sizeof(struct App));

    printf("Malloc worked. sizeof line: %li\n", sizeof(line));

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("about to parse line\n");
        ParseLine(app, line);
    }

    return app;
}
```

And it does output `file is null`, so I guess the problem lies in fopen.

Comment: I added and edit, file does appear to be null after fopen. I did use fgets to get the filename, I will try getting rid of the newline

Comment: Tip: when checking a string entry, put brackets round it, like `"[%s]"` and the newline or other whitespace is then more obvious.

Comment: This question needs a [mre]!

Comment: You did not check `fopen` or `malloc`...

Comment: Hi Carter, I don't understand where you malloc a struct of type App, then printf that the malloc succeeded without checking the pointer returned from malloc. Also, you then print that the malloc was for sizeof (line). What is the relationship between Line and struct App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newline character messed up fopen, adding `filepath[strcspn(filepath, "\n")]=0;` solved it. Thank you for the help, especially user3121023.